# Loading MySQL Dump From one Character Set to Another

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump, character-set

As you can see from these configuration differences, the MySQL server is configured with `latin1`, while the MariaDB server is using `utf8mb4`:

```
Variable                  MySQL Server       MariaDB Server
========================= ================== ===================
character_set_client      latin1             utf8mb4
character_set_connection  latin1             utf8mb4
character_set_database    latin1             utf8mb4
character_set_results     latin1             utf8mb4
character_set_server      latin1             utf8mb4
collation_connection      latin1_swedish_ci  utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database        latin1_swedish_ci  utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server          latin1_swedish_ci  utf8mb4_general_ci
```

UTF8 is the preferred character set, but am I going to run into issues when loading data from one database to the other? Are there steps I should take? Change configurations?

MySQL Dump command:

```
mysqldump --routines --single-transaction --quick --skip-extended-insert
```

Here are the directives from the MySQL Dump file:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: See what the dump says -- it may be explicit enough to deal with the issue.

Comment: @RickJames - I've updated the post. Will those directives ensure everything works as it should?

Comment: The `SET NAMES utf8` says that the file is encoded utf8, not latin1.  But, that could be OK.  What parameters were used on `mysqldump`?

Comment: The difference between utf8 and utf8mb4 is only in Emoji and Chinese (and some more obscure stuff); none of that is expressible in latin1.  That is, I don't see `utf8` versus `utf8mb4` being a problem _in this case_.

Comment: @RickJames - I've added the `mysqldump` command with arguments to the post.

Comment: Do you have a particular cell you can check?  Have you performed the load?  It is quite possible that nothing is wrong in the resulting database.

Comment: @RickJames - I've done the load, but I don't know of specific data to check. I'll poke around.

Comment: If possible, get `HEX(col)` -- it will be easy to see if the hex is latin1 or utf8.  And that must match the definition of the column -- so please run and provide the corresponding `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Either charset can work.